# Series involving Earth meeting a galactic civilization and using maple syrup sales for revenue

Tags: story-identification

I started reading this series a few years back. It wasn't finished and now I can't remember the author or titles.

The series involved Earth discovering or being discovered by a galactic civilization with multiple species. The protagonist uses maple syrup sales to generate revenue and eventually uses giant mirrors to melt asteroids and form massive ships to defend Earth.

They eventually counterattack at least one of the alien species trying to dominate Earth.

I've tried to rediscover this series and finish it for years and just cannot find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  About when was "a few years back?"  The more details we have the more we can help you.  Do you remember any of the covers?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about the other points, but maple syrup being a commodity in great demand for aliens is an important plot point in John Ringo's [*Troy Rising*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?28284) series, starting with [*Live Free or Die*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1068157) (2010).

Part 1 of *Live Free or Die* is "The Maple Syrup War," and several of the reviewers on the [Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6713634-live-free-or-die) make note of its use as a driver of the plot.

The blurb for the first book:

> *First Contact Was Friendly*
>
> When aliens trundled a gate to other worlds into the solar system, the world reacted with awe, hope and fear. But the first aliens to come through, the Glatun, were peaceful traders and the world breathed a sigh of relief.
>
> *Who Controls the Orbitals, Controls the World*
>
> When the Horvath came through, they announced their ownership by dropping rocks on three cities and gutting them. Since then, they've held Terra as their own personal fiefdom. With their control of the orbitals, there's no way to win and earth's governments have accepted the status quo.
>
> *Live Free or Die.*
>
> To free the world from the grip of the Horvath is going to take an unlikely hero. A hero unwilling to back down to alien or human governments, unwilling to live in slavery and with enough hubris, if not stature, to think he can win. Fortunately, there's Tyler Vernon. And he has bigger plans than just getting rid of the Horvath.

*Troy Rising* is a trilogy, with *Live Free or Die* being followed by [*Citadel*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1206746) and [*The Hot Gate*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1236100), both released in 2011.

Comment: I can verify the using mirrors to hollow out asteroids and use them as giant mobile battleships. Interesting note, originally, this was supposed to tie into the history of the *Schlock Mercenary* webcomic (with Tyler Vernon as a science fiction webcomic artist meant to be a reference to Howard Tayler), but there was some miscommunication, which resulted in it not matching up properly, and so John Ringo retooled it to be an original work.